# Redirect external html file to Phonegap index.html

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I want to use an external service in my `PhoneGap` app.
The external service take a success url to redirect user to the original page when the process has been completed.
What url should I pass to the service to get back to my PhoneGap app?
I have tried with 
`window.location = 'file:///android_asset/www/index.html'` in Android device. But it is not working.

Does anyone know how to make this call work? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

location do not use here.

So you need to call [InAppBrowser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html) in phonegap for calling external pages. when you get success at the time you close inappbrowser.

If InAppBrowser browser not convenient means use [ChildBrowser](https://github.com/alunny/ChildBrowser) plugins for showing external web page. its better than InAppBrowser